# Component doesn't load in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return
        <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
} });

var HelloReact = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {message:'default'}
}, 
updateMessage:function(){
   console.info('UpdateMessge');
   this.setState({message:this.refs.messageTextBox.value});
   },
render:function(){
 return <div>
             <HelloMessage message='Hello React'/>
             <input type='text' ref='messageTextBox'/>
             <button onClick={this.updateMessage}>Update</button>
              <div>{this.state.message}</div>
        </div>
}
});
```

I am unable to load HelloMessage component in HelloReact component. Below is the error I get in browser console

Uncaught Error: HelloMessage.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: I implore you to adopt a vaguely-standard style of bracing, and to be consistent with your braces and indentation, at least when asking questions. The above is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion. Remove the new line between `return` and `<h2>` in `HelloMessage`, because as-is it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks are *sometimes* significant in JavaScript (and remember, JSX is just JavaScript) thanks to the horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion. The most notorious of those places is: A line break after `return`. Your render isn't returning anything, because ASI is inserting a `;` after `return`:

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return; // <============================== here
        <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
} });
```

**Never** put a line break after `return` and before the thing being returned. Either put the `h2` on the same line:

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
} });
```

...or use `()` to prevent ASI messing up your code:

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return (
        <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
    );
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your variant HelloMessage has empty return  because you break line `return
            <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>`

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return
        <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
} });
```

Javascript has autocomplete with semicolons and you have `return ;`

Change to

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
render:function() {
    return <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>
} });
```